# Write text on image C# with accurate location

Tags: c#, text, drawing

The thing is that I’m trying to write txt on image using setting from an editable C# label through my custom edit panel (txt, font name, font size, font style, location), then after I finish the edit I press add the text to the image!

It always gets written in wrong location and wrong font size
The picture is loaded in picture box and the size mode is stretched.
 [The interface preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8HkZ.png)

Code:

```
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
RectangleF rectf = new RectangleF(NamePreviewPanel.Location.X  , NamePreviewPanel.Location.Y, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
StringFormat format = new StringFormat()
            {
                Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
                LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
            };
// add the color
int gW = (int)(TestFontLable.Text.Length * TestFontLable.Font.Size);
gW = gW == 0 ? 10 : gW;
LinearGradientBrush LGBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(rectf, TestFontLable.ForeColor, TestFontLable.ForeColor, LinearGradientMode.Vertical);
g.DrawString(TestFontLable.Text, TestFontLable.Font, LGBrush, rectf, format);
pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

Comment: If you coordinates are specific to the PictureBox, then why is your rectangle using the NamePreviewPanel coordinates as the starting point?  Dispose your graphic objects.

Comment: because i move the NamePreviewPanel  to what ever location i want to add the text in the image got it?

Comment: A PictureBox usually isn't a container, so there probably isn't a relationship between your panel and your rectangle coordinates.  We can only guess.

Comment: pictureBox1.Controls.Add(NamePreviewPanel); isn't enough?

Comment: How are we to know that until you tell us?  Where's this panel in the image?  Where is the PictureBox?  It's unclear to me what is what here.

Comment: this name preview panel is on top of the picture box -->have the property of filling the form

Comment: i can upload the source code if its possible

Comment: @Pop Max  So you decide where that text should be positioned by moving around that panel? And the reference rectangle you pass to `.DrawString()` points to that (x,y,,) position, it's width being the bitmap's? Even if you add this "panel" to the picturebox controls, it's relative position won't change. It's always relative to its parent container. Isn't it better to use the mouse pointer to choose the desired location? And maybe use `Graphics.MeasureString()` to check if the text string fits?